# in function findVowels for loop increment doesn't work, only prints the last vowel?

Tags: java

here in the findVowels function I am trying to print every 2nd vowel which I got from outPut function in rev but it just print the last vowel only....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelString {

    static char rev;
    static String str;
    static int count = 0;

    void inPut() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
        sc.close();
    }

    void outPut() {
        System.out.println(str);
        // int length=str.length();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) {
                if ((str.charAt(i) == 'a') || (str.charAt(i) == 'e')
                        || (str.charAt(i) == 'i') || (str.charAt(i) == 'o')
                        || (str.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
                    rev = str.charAt(i);
                    System.out.print(rev);
                    count++;
                }

            }
            // System.out.println(rev);
            System.out.println("\ntotal " + count);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    void findVowels(char word) {
        this.rev = word;
        String asta = String.valueOf(rev);
        for (int i = 0; i <= asta.length() - 1; i = +2) {
            char nawa = asta.charAt(i);
            System.out.println("something = " + nawa);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VowelString vS = new VowelString();
        vS.inPut();
        // System.out.println("Values of Input " + vS);
        vS.outPut();
        // System.out.println("Values of OutPut " + vS);
        vS.findVowels(rev);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only saving the last vowel you find to rev

```
rev = str.charAt(i);
```

inside output(). So rev in findVowel will only be 1 char it seems. Perhaps you mean to say

```
rev += str.charAt(i);
```

Though this is not recommendable in a general setting it will probably suffice for your problem unless you have huge Strings.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code should print all vowels. Not only the last as you say. But also not every 2nd as you want. It's also poorly written. Here's one way to print every second vowel, and a bit better written overall:

```
        for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    count++;
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print(c);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
```